# executing a command on multiple paired files

Tags: bash, unix, fastq

Say I have a command, command.py, and it pairs together files, `File_01_R1.fastq` to `File_01_R2.fastq`. The command executed on a single pair looks like this:

```
command.py -f File_01_R1.fastq -r File_01_R2.fastq
```

I have many files however, each with a R1 and R2 version. How can I tell this command to go through every file I have, so it also executes

```
command.py -f File_02_R1.fastq -r File_02_R2.fastq
command.py -f File_03_R1.fastq -r File_03_R2.fastq
```

and so on.

Comment: they don't, i have updated this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a simple [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for f in *_R1.fastq; do
    echo command.py -f "$f" -r "${f%_R1.fastq}_R2.fastq"
done
```

This will just print out what's to be executed. Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Loop over all R1.fastq files
for f in File_*_R1.fastq; do
    # Replace R1 with R2 in the filename and run the command on both files.
    command.py -f "$f" -r "${f/_R1./_R2.}"
done; unset -v f
```

As @gniourf_gniourf indicates in his comment my answer is slightly less safe than his in that it may match at an incorrect location in the filename (whereas his is anchored at the end).

Comment: Hopefully there will be no files named `File_somethingR1something_R1.fastq`.